Create 'static Stream from a Stream which is lifetime-coupled to its source
I have a certain API I have to use:
struct API;
struct Ctrl;
impl API{
    fn get_stream(&self) -> (impl Stream<Item = i32> + '_, Ctrl) {
        (futures::stream::iter(1..=5), Ctrl{}) // place holder stream
    }
}

The API provides a struct in an Arc, which provides a stream. While I need a 'static Stream, the stream provided is lifetime coupled with its source ('API' struct), which seems to make it impossible to move it outside the scope (local scope, function).
As I understand it, the lifetime of the API instance must be at least as long as the stream exists.
Therefore, creating a stream which captures its source didn't seem far fetched. I attempted to implement a Stream which would just have the source as a struct member, because I couldn't find a factory method in existing libraries, which would do that:
use futures::stream::{Stream, StreamExt};
use futures::task::Poll;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::task::Context;

pub struct Combine<S> {
    instance: Arc<API>,
    stream: S,
}
impl<S> Combine<S>
where
    S: Stream<Item = i32>,
{
    fn new(instance: Arc<API>, stream: S) -> Self {
        Combine {
            instance,
            stream,
        }
    }
}

impl<S> Stream for Combine<S>
where
    S: Stream<Item = i32> + Unpin,
{
    type Item = i32;
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let this = self.get_mut();
        this.stream.poll_next_unpin(cx)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let combined = {
        // given
        let instance = Arc::new(API{});
        
        let (stream, _ctrl) = instance.get_stream();
        Combine::new(instance, stream)
    };

    tokio::pin!(combined);
    while let Some(item) = combined.next().await {
        println!("Received item: {}", item);
    }
} 

However I haven't been succesful.
In the given code, the compiler doesn't understand that the struct Combine holds an Arc which will survive the struct's lifetime.
It seems like the problem falls into the category of self referential structs, however I haven't been successful with libraries like ouroboros or safer_owning_ref either. In both cases I was not able to return a Stream in a closure to which & API was passed.
I tried the following:

return a Box::new(stream) // stream being equally retrieved defined as above, just within the closure
return stream
return &stream

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0831c173256f257ce514114e334543a7
Note: Rust Nightly would be OK

You might be able to use a crate like Ouroboros to create a self-referencing struct. Here is an example that creates an iterator, but the same principle should apply to a stream: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cfe20adb9cbb407d0bf16c7b84d04f2

This is a self-referential struct, and indeed a self-referential structs crate will be a viable way to solve this. To clarify: are you looking for an example of ouroboros or other crates?

If it is possible to implement it with ouroboros, feel free to show it. As explained, I couldn't get an ouroboros solution to work. @user3815162342, thanks will try to adapt it to streams, and see if I can make it work from this

This feel like design problem, why are you trying to define custom stream, if the api already give you stream, why define a Combine at all?
Anyways, this feel like a bit of a hack, but I spawned a new tokio thread to handle the stream,
also, I'm not sure if you will need _ctrl, but in case you do, the commented code are for sending the data back to main thread.
use tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let combined = {
        // given
        let instance = Arc::new(API{});
        
        let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(256);

        // let _ctrl = 
        {
            let instance = instance.clone();
            // let (o_tx, o_rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let (mut stream, ctrl) = instance.get_stream();
                // let _ = o_tx.send(ctrl);
                while let Some(i) = stream.next().await {
                    tx.send(i).await.unwrap();
                }
            });
            // o_rx.blocking_recv().unwrap()
        };
            
        Combine::new(instance, ReceiverStream::new(rx))
    };

    tokio::pin!(combined);
    while let Some(item) = combined.next().await {
        println!("Received item: {}", item);
    }
} 

Output
Received item: 1
Received item: 2
Received item: 3
Received item: 4
Received item: 5


because I need the stream for something else which can only deal with 'static streams. I implemented something similar to this as a workaround
